# Delete all data in a table but in one column in access 2007 using Sql query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using access 2007, I have almost 40 columns in a table and i want to reset all data to null except for one column. I am looking for the proper query like this

```
Delete table.* from table except one column
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: This is a better question with more detail than the referenced question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UPDATE.

```
UPDATE table
SET
  col1 = null,
  col2 = null,
  col4 = null,
  ....
WHERE 1=1
```

This will leave all the data in col3 intact.